# Scroll Horizontally on hover only runs once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a simple scroll left and right div on hover. I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong, I hover, but it only moves the 50 specified in the `if` statement. Do I need to add some kind of loop while I'm still hovering? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Basically, I want to be able to hover over the two black boxes `right` and `left` and while it's hovered move right or left, when I remove the mouse it should stop.

```js
$("#left").hover(function() {
  var leftPos = $('#wrapper').scrollLeft();
  $("#wrapper").animate({
    scrollLeft: leftPos - 50
  }, 1);
});

$("#right").hover(function() {
  var leftPos = $('#wrapper').scrollLeft();
  $("#wrapper").animate({
    scrollLeft: leftPos + 50
  }, 1);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#left {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: black;
}

#right {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: black;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

#inner_wrap {
  width: 4000px;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

#firstcontent {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20vw;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
}

.thumbone {
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  display: inline-block;
}

.thumbtwo {
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://corporate3.bdjobs.com/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="inner_wrap">
    <div id="firstcontent">hover or scroll</div>
    <div class="thumbone"></div>
    <div class="thumbtwo"></div>
    <div class="thumbone"></div>
    <div class="thumbtwo"></div>
    <div class="thumbone"></div>
    <div class="thumbtwo"></div>
    <div class="thumbone"></div>
    <div class="thumbtwo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Link to script
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wsemLhtz/116/)

[also a side note, why does this work only on jsfiddle and no where else?]

Comment: what do you want i did not understand ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122555/scroll-the-div-content-in-a-controlled-manner-on-hovering-over-an-image?rq=1

Comment: It is working here, using stack snippet at FF browser. May be error comes at console due another issue, check your console error list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is because the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events (which underpin the `hover()` logic) only fire once, when the mouse enters/leaves the targeted element. If you want to repeatedly perform an action *whilst* the element is over those elements you'll need to implement your own logic.

To achieve this you can use an interval within the `mouseenter` handler of the `hover()` to repeatedly shift the scroll position of the required element. Then in the `mouseleave` you can clear that timer.

Also note that you can DRY up your code by using a common class on both elements along with a `data` attribute to govern the movement increment per tick of the interval. Try this:

```js
var timer;
$('.hover-scroll').hover(function() {
  var increment = $(this).data('pos');
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    var leftPos = $("#wrapper").scrollLeft();
    $("#wrapper").animate({
      scrollLeft: leftPos + increment
    }, 1);
  }, 50);
}, function() {
  clearInterval(timer);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#left {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: black;
}

#right {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: black;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

#inner_wrap {
  width: 4000px;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

#firstcontent {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20vw;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
}

.thumbone {
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  display: inline-block;
}

.thumbtwo {
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://corporate3.bdjobs.com/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="left" class="hover-scroll" data-pos="-50"></div>
<div id="right" class="hover-scroll" data-pos="50"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="inner_wrap">
    <div id="firstcontent">hover or scroll</div>
    <div class="thumbone"></div>
    <div class="thumbtwo"></div>
    <div class="thumbone"></div>
    <div class="thumbtwo"></div>
    <div class="thumbone"></div>
    <div class="thumbtwo"></div>
    <div class="thumbone"></div>
    <div class="thumbtwo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to speed up or slow down the scroll, change the delay on the interval

Comment: That's a really nice way to do it with the `data` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your awnser. I like this approach! I'll give it a try when I'm back at my pc. I agree with takit cool way to do it with the data attribute!

Comment: It Clearly works on jsfiddle but, it wont work anywhere else? really confusing. Thanks anyway!

Comment: If that's the case, check the console. You've likely missed out the reference to jquery.js, or put it in the wrong place, or are missing the document.ready handler (which jsFiddle adds by default for you)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  $ is not defined. its the   window.onload=function(){ i was missing. Silly me

Comment: That's two separate issues. `$ is undefined` means you need to include jQuery.js in the page. Also, don't use `window.onload = ...` Use jQuery's document.ready handler. See this guide for more info: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you, ive used document ready handler instead then. Thank you for the documentation, I will read through all that.